# Problem to data parsing from array in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have data with following format.

```
      Data (
    {
    "retweet_count" = 0;
    retweeted = false;
      user =         {
         verified = false;
             };
},
    {
    "retweet_count" = 4;
    retweeted = false;

    user =         {
                    verified = false;
    };
},
    {

    "retweet_count" = 2;
    retweeted = false;
    user =         {
        verified = false;
    };
},
```

)

I have to order these array ( Stored_Data Array) in Descending order of "retweet_count" value. like data should be "retweet_count=4", "retweet_count=2" and "retweet_count=0". My code is below but this is not ordering data with retweet_count value.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor_twitter;
sortDescriptor_twitter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"retweet_count"
                                              ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors_2 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor_twitter];
NSArray *retweetValues;
retweetValues = [Stored_Data sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors_2];
```

What is wrong with my code ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sort descriptors access object properties, not dictionary keys.  Try using sortedArrayUsingFunction.